# MySQL .frm/.myd/.myi

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with test data. I have been modifying routines and triggers in this database. I have a new .tar file containing *.frm, *.myd, *.myi, *.trn, and *.trg files for this same database with production data. I want to take only the actual data from the tar file and move it into my existing database. May I simply move the *.myd and *.myi files from the tar file to the current folder for my database without corrupting the schema?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to do that just fine. frm, myd and myi are MyISAM tables and you can copy and moves those around without corrupting anything. Although, technically you should have the database shutdown when you do that. If that is not an option, make sure you run "flush tables" before copying anything.

Once you copy those into the mysql data directory, make sure the privileges are correct. Then you should be able to see them in mysql. As I said, you can do this while mysql is running, but I don't recommend it.

You cannot do this with Innodb tables (i.e. .ibd extension).

Comment: thank you for your informative answer. could you please let me know how to access the var folder and a MySQL database folder with .frm, .MYD and .MYI files of each table in CPanel? also, I submitted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667759/how-to-access-the-var-folder-and-a-mysql-database-folder-with-frm-myd-and-my