# How to access the var folder and a MySQL database folder with .frm, .MYD and .MYI files of each table in CPanel?

Tags: mysql, database, .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

I have a website on a dedicated server which a friend of mine is the administrator. My question is how to access the var folder where my database is located in for direct access to .frm, .MYD and .MYI files of each of my tables in Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

in linux (ubuntu) mysql files will be located at **/var/lib/mysql/**

you can access by putty. This directory is not permitted by the users.

Use "**sudo su**" command, then try to access this directory.